# Generate URL for recorded videos of Team Meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have utilized the Graph API to schedule an Calender Event of online meeting enabled, with the meeting provider as "teamsForBusiness". The meeting is successfully scheduled and I also can use the URL to join the meeting and record my meeting.

I also have a requirement to fetch the URL of recorded meeting video. Unfortunately I cannot find a way or any existing documentation that could help me achieve my goal in getting the URL of my recorded meeting video. I would like to know of any possible ways to extract the URL of the recorded videos.